# Change location of custom settings page in wordpress backend

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i adapt the following code to show my custom “Theme Settings” page under “appearence” and NOT under “settings” in the wordpress backend?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'theme_options_page'); function theme_options_page() { add_options_page('Theme Settings', 'Theme Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'build_options_page');
```

[Here](http://clicknathan.com/web-design/create-wordpress-theme-settings-page/) you can find the full code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `add_submenu_page`

```
add_submenu_page( themes.php, 'Title of Page', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'custom_options', 'custom_function' );
function custom_function()
{
    // add your form code here or include a file here
}
```

for under Appearance use `themes.php` as `parent_slug`

or you can also use

using `add_theme_page`

```
add_theme_page( 'this is page Title', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'custom_options', 'custom_function' );
```

for more info please check 
[you can check](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)

Comment: thx, can you help me to change my code to show it under appearance - i tried - but no idea what to do exactly

Comment: Please follow the url under "Here" in my question - there you will find the code im using. thx